# Why does this Vue.js component display a function's body instead of it's return value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a small **[Todo App](https://github.com/Ajax30/Vue-3-To-Do/tree/with_our_api)** with Vue 3 on the front-end and Slim 3 on the back-end (API).

In `App.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header 
    title="My todo list" 
    :unsolvedTodos = unsolvedTodos
    />

    <List 
      :todos="todos"
      :dataIsLoaded=dataIsLoaded
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo" 
      @toggle-todo="toggleTodo" />

    <Footer
      :isValidInput=isValidInput
      newTitle = ""
      placeholder= "+ Add new todo"
      validationMsg = "Please add at least 3 characters"
      @add-todo="addTodo"
      />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
 // more code here
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    List,
    Footer
  },

  data() {
    return {
      apiUrl: "http://todo.com/api",
      dataIsLoaded: false,
      isValidInput: true,
      todos: [],
      unsolvedTodos: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    showTodos: function(){
      axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.todos = response.data;
      })
     .then(this.getUnsolvedTodos)
     .then(this.dataIsLoaded = true);
    },
    
    // more methods
    addTodo: function(newTitle){
     const newToDo = {
        title: newTitle,
        completed: 0
      }
     
      if(newTitle.length > 2){
        this.isValidInput = true;
        axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/todo/add`, newToDo);
      } else {
        this.isValidInput = false;
      }
    }
  },

 watch: {
    todos() {
      this.showTodos();
    }
 }
</script>
```

In `components\Footer.vue`, I have:

```
<template>
  <footer>
    <form @submit.prevent="$emit('add-todo', newTitle)">
      <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="newTitle">
      <span class="error" v-if="!isValidInput">{{validationMsg}}</span>
    </form>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer',

  props: {
    placeholder: String,
    validationMsg: String,
    isValidInput: Boolean
  },
  data () {
    return {
     newTitle: String,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### The problem

The input (of type text) used to add a new todo, displays a function's body, instead of its return value:

```
function String() { [native code] }
```

Why does that happen? What's a fast and reliable fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `newTitle` was declared as props.
data is a function that returns object. `newTitle` is an object key and the value(String in this case) will actually be placed in text field.

```
data () {
  return {
    newTitle: String,
  }
}
```

It should be like below

```
data () {
  return {
   newTitle: '',
  }
}
```

Actually `''` is initial value and `String` as an initial value is `function String() { [native code] }`

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitTitle()">
  <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="newTitle">
  <span class="error" v-if="!isValidInput">{{validationMsg}}</span>
</form>

methods: {
  submitTitle() {
    this.$emit('add-todo', this.newTitle)
    this.newTitle = ''
  }
}
```

Comment: That is correct. How do I empty the input after adding a todo?

Comment: You can bind a function at submit event. so first set newTitle empty and then emit the event to the parent component